# Refresh page problems TypeScript/Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a div that I want to display in my template

```
*ngIf="!isCalendarMode"
```

and in my TypeScript file I declared the field:

```
  isCalendarMode = false;
  subs = new Subscription();

      ngOnInit() {

    
    this.subs.add(this.router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe(_ => {
        this.isCalendarMode = this.router.url.includes('calendar');

    }));
```

The problem is:
When I first load the page, the 'isCalendarMode' with be false, and it will appear the display.
Then when I route to 'calendar' the 'isCalendarMode' will be true and okay that is want I want, but if I refresh the same page the 'isCalendarMode' will go again false and I will get the display which I don't want in this scenario.

I need the 'isCalendarMode' to stay true when I refresh the page.

Comment: You can use localstorage or cookies for that.

Comment: I need to fix it in my ngOnInit() method

Answer (score 0):

```
//instead of isCalendarMode = false
isCalendarMode =  this.router.url.includes('calendar');
```

You don't get the navigationend event if you're not navigating

Comment: I solved it, similar to your idea.Thank you

Comment: I dont have reputation to make the answer useful

Comment: What was the solution? I can change my answer